# Azure Mobile Service Timeouts because of SQL Server

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am running a complex spatial calculations query wrapped inside a Table Value Function of SQL Server. Which run quite nicely on local machine and return results in less than 5 secs every time and on Azure sometimes it returns results in 10 secs and and sometime same query takes up to 30 secs.

I don't understand it what I am missing here. And when it takes around 30 secs to return result it generate timeout on service side because as I understand timeout is 30 secs on custom api's. How do you suggest on handling it.

[image: Execution plan of Query]

Thanks,

Attiqe

Comment: You wouldn't want your clients to wait more than 30 seconds for a result (I assume), so perhaps you can cache the values?  Alternatively, if you upgrade your SQL tier, the query should execute faster.

Comment: @lindydonna I am getting result set based on lat/long in Table Value Function how can I apply cache in it and also which SQL tier would you recommend.

Comment: @lindydonna also for information how can we change default timeout.